# How to send several data in JNI between C and Java

Tags: java, c, android-studio, java-native-interface

For my project, I need to get a buffer send by a Java application into my C application.
Now I'm having a simple int array in java, that i want to modify some of his data and return it.

In C It's possible to modify, by using a pointer, but if I have understood, It's not possible to use this method between Java and C.

But my function need several buffer of several types and I need to send all of these into the Java part of the application.

So, I have write this code (with just one buffer in input and an object in output) that not work cause of difference types :

**In main.c :**

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
Java_com_example_testnewsensivic_Deuxthread_main(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jintArray jsignal,
                                                    jstring string) {


jclass stringClazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Object");
jobjectArray stringArray = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 3, stringClazz, NULL);

jstring var1 = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "test1");
(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, stringArray, 0, var1);
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, var1);


int       ar[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
jsize len = sizeof(ar)/sizeof(*ar);
jintArray var2 = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, len);
(*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, var2, 0, len, ar);

const jsize length2 = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, var2);
jint *oarr2 = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, var2, NULL);


jstring var3 = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "test3");
(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, stringArray, 2, var3);
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, var3);

return stringArray;
}
```

**In Java code :**

```
            int[] z = {1, 2, 3, 4};
            str = main(z, "DeuxThread");
            System.out.println(str[0].toString());
            System.out.println(str[1]);
            System.out.println(str[2].toString());
```

Have you any idea to help me to resolve this problem ?

Best Regards.

**EDIT More precision :**

I'm sorry if It's not understandable, but to resume, my Java application get several buffer mainly, some int array and String define like that :

`int [] array1; int [] array2; String str;`

and when I'm calling my C function with their array to the argument of my C function, like that :

`main(array1, array2, str);`

I would like to get their array and String, modified by my main function (on the C code), for example to return an Object with theire new array and String modified.

Comment: _What_ is not working?

Comment: It's my main.c cause I want to define an object with IntArray and String that It's apparently impossible but I would like to know if an issue of my problem is possible.

Comment: It's not clear to me from your question exactly what your data will look like. You may have to define a new Java class that can hold all possible kinds of buffer elements, and create an array of that type. This doesn't really seem related to JNI though, as you'd have the same problem if you were programming in plain Java.

Comment: I'm starting from the android development and I'm sorry if It's not understandable, but to resume, my Java application get several buffer mainly, some int array define like that : 
"int [] array1;
int [] array2;
String str;"

and when I'm calling my C function with their array to the argument of my C function, like that :
"main(array1, array2, str);"
I would like to get their array and String, modified by my main function (on the C code), for example to return an Object with theire new array and String modified.